# tests for convergence of cos(pi/2n-1)-cos(pi/n)

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

On my way to saying that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(cos(\pi/(2n-1))-cos(\pi/2n))$ diverges,

I figured I would re-write the expression $cos(\pi/(2n-1))-cos(\pi/2n)$ 
as $(-1)^{n+1}cos(\pi/n)$.

because  $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{n+1}cos(\pi/n)\neq0$.

But that is confusing for me, because I want it to mean that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(cos(\pi/(2n-1))-cos(\pi/2n))\neq0$, 
which is clearly untrue since it becomes $1-1=0$.

(1) why If $\sum a_n=\sum b_n$, why can't we assume that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} b_n $ ? Will condensing terms be a frequent way to solve problems?

and

(2) Intuitively I can see that $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(-1)^{n+1}cos(\pi/n)\neq0$, but my attemps to show it are circular and flawed. My instinct says to re-write it as $cos(\pi/(2n-1))-cos(\pi/2n)$. How do you (formally) compute the limit an expression that has $(-1)^n$ in it?

Comment: The series $\sum \left(\cos(\pi/(2n-1))-\cos(\pi/(2n))\right)$ converges. Of course, $\sum (-1)^{n+1} \cos(\pi/n)$ diverges.

Comment: As to worrying about minus signs, we have $\lim a_n=0$ if and only if $\lim|a_n|=0$. A formal $\epsilon$-$N$ proof is quick.

Comment: As to $\sum (-1)^{n+1} \cos(\pi/n)$ diverging, it does but in an interesting way: Just like 1-1+1-1+1... it has only two limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum converges -
each term is
$O(1/n^3)$.

Since
$\cos(x)-\cos(y)
=-2\sin(\frac{x+y}{2})\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})
$,
if
$x = \frac{\pi}{2n-1}$
and
$y = \frac{\pi}{2n}$
,
$\frac{x+y}{2}
=\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n})
=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{4n-1}{(2n-1)(2n)}
$
and
$\frac{x-y}{2}
=\frac{\pi}{2}(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n})
=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)}
$
so
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n-1})-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})
=-2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{4n+1}{(2n-1)(2n)})
\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n)})
$.

The first term is of order
$O(1/n)$
and the second term
is of order
$O(1/n^2)$
so their product
is of order
$O(1/n^3)$
so their sum converges.

Another way to see this is,
since
$\cos(z)
= 1-\frac1{2z^2}+ O(1/z^4)$
for small $z$,
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n-1})
= 1-\frac{\pi^2}{2(2n-1)^2}+O(1/n^4)
$
and
$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})
=1-\frac{\pi^2}{2(2n)^2}+O(1/n^4)
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n-1})
-\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n})
&= (1-\frac{\pi^2}{2(2n-1)^2}+O(1/n^4))-(1-\frac{\pi^2}{2(2n)^2}+O(1/n^4))\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{2(2n)^2}-\frac{\pi^2}{2(2n-1)^2}+O(1/n^4)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{2}(\frac{(2n-1)^2-(2n)^2}{(2n)^2(2n-1)^2})+O(1/n^4)\\
&=\frac{\pi^2(-4n+1)}{2(2n)^2(2n-1)^2}+O(1/n^4)\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{8n^3}+O(1/n^4)\\
&=O(1/n^3)+O(1/n^4)\\
&=O(1/n^3)
\end{array}
$